# What is this sliding cabinet door with "shades" called, and where can I find info on it?

Tags: tool-identification, cabinetry

I remembered I saw a video/picture about cabinet equipped with a sliding door, just like window shades was installed vertically all around the cabinet. You can slide the window shades like door (made from many pieces of wood) to open the cabinet. But I couldn't find the link anymore. Please direct me to the link if you happen to know it. Thanks.

Edit: Here is what I can find that is close to my recollection: https://image.rakuten.co.jp/ffws/cabinet/d_item9/s0500602_img05.gif

The sliding bellow in the above gif file seems a little bulky to me. I hope the leaves of the bellow is much thinner.

Comment: Hi Jasper, welcome to SE. Please see, [How do I ask a good question?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to a "tambour door"?

[image]

Comment: Good call.  Perhaps a link and a credit for the picture?

Comment: Answers shouldn't be in the form of a question or even ask questions of the OP, which indicates that the Question at the very least needs revision or clarification in the Comments.

Comment: @Graphus This is what is called a "rhetorical question".  It's not really intended that the OP actually answer it.  You're being fairly pedantic here.  Do you really think the quality of the answer would be improved by changing that to "I think you're" instead of "are you"?

Comment: That's not really a rhetorical question, but I won't argue the point.

Comment: This looks like a beautify structure. Please see my edit to the OP.

Comment: The Tambour door on the "Bellow" unit in the link  probably does not roll around itself like the one you have pictured. It probably slides in a  hidden passage behind the side and back panels. I saw an episode of the Woodsmith shop that detailed how to make a similar unit.